# How to read the raw request body in Wt using WEnviroment?

Tags: wt

I'm trying to implement a JSON-RPC middleware using Wt. I can read raw request body using WResource, no problem. But I need WebSockets and my Wt server using WResource ( I'm calling server.addResource ) don't answer properly to WebSockets clients. Maybe this is normal?

Second way, I made addEntryPoint to a customized WApplication, that work well for WebSocket, thanks Wt!, but I can't imagine how to read the JSON sent in POST requests.

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately WResource doesn't support websockets. In a WApplication, all communication is done by Wt's rendering engine, so you can't interfere by that mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, sound that Wt as RPC middle ware is not the better way.